# AWS S3 create a policy to just keep the latest 2 objects when continues put in same object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

When keep in putting the same objects(like backup files) to a S3 versioning enabled bucket. It is getting bigger and bigger, Don't want to keep all of them. just need to keep last 2 files and delete all rest files

Don't want to use any other programming methods other than enable terraform policy.

Want to created a policy triggered by current backup file dropping that can delete the old files if we already have 2 or more. result after the policy executed: the total backup files will be last 2 base on time stamp (or version)

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by lifecycle rule. not by version. but by time